# Devices are not compatible with my application from Google Play Store

Tags: android-studio, google-play, apk

I have upload my application is Play Store in Beta test, but all my device said : **your device is not compatible with this version**. When I check Google Play Console it said that **0 device are compatible with my app**, why?

Comment: Can you show your AndroidManifest.xml? Some elements there can restrict the availability of your app.

Answer (score 0):

My AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.luzwitz.mapsroute">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY" />

    <service android:name=".service.LocationMaps" />

    <service android:name=".service.MessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityHome"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityLogin"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityRoute"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityMaps"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityFriendly"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_friends"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityMessage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_messaging"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityAlert"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

</application>
```